# How can I /summon specific types of sapling items?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

I'm making a custom map and need to summon different types of saplings.

I've tried this:

```
/summon Item 8 58 -1005 {Item:{id:sapling,Count:1},PickupDelay:10000,Age:-32768,data:5}
```

but this just summons regular oak saplings. The data tag at the end doesn't seem to do anything, so I need to know the proper way to change the data value in order to get different types of saplings.

Thanks in advance for any help!

Comment: What MC version?

Comment: Also, are you trying to summon the sapling to be on a piece of dirt, an item to pick up, or into a player's inventory?

Comment: in Minecraft 1.8.8, and I'm trying to get it to be an item entity on the ground not to be picked up but just displayed

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Item entities doesn't have a data tag, for different metadata use the Damage tag.

```
/summon Item 8 58 -1005 {Item:{id:sapling,Count:1,Damage:5},PickupDelay:10000,Age:-32768}
```

Comment: Also note that the `Damage` tag is inside the Item-Entities `Item` tag, rather than the Item-Entities tag itself. Damage (=Data Value) means different things for different items, so it only makes sense as a property of the specific item rather than the general entity.

Answer (score 0):

Try and change the [id](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Sapling#ID), which might help because of the id command. The id depends on the edition. Example:

```
/summon Item 8 58 -1005 {Item:{id:spruce_sapling,Count:1},PickupDelay:10000,Age:-32768,data:5}
```